# Should we synonymise [science] -> [research]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently we have [research](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) (7 questions)

> Use this tag when you are asking about scientific studies. If you are asking about experiments done on animals (an ethical issue for veg*ns), please use the tag [animal-experimentation](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-experimentation)

And [science](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) (1 question)

> Use this tag for questions concerning the process of science.

I cannot see any difference between these tags for our purposes.

Should they be synonymised?

Comment: [research] has a unclear tag wiki right now, its intended use appears to be "asking _for_ scientific studies". [science] would be used for questions pertaining to things such as animal testing/experimentation, and other questions that pertain to science in general.

Comment: @Riker are you talking about the revised usage guidance or the usage guidance before I suggested an edit to it?

Comment: I'm talking about the one in the question right now. FWIW, I approved your edit (actually like 5 of them, but _please_ remember your ending punctuation) so I know the current revision.

Comment: Sadly, it didn't occur to me to change that at the time (when I approved your edit). I'll probably edit it if a consensus is reached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they shouldn't be synonymized.

[research](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) is for questions that are asking for scientific studies for answers. For example, [Are there any studies comparing genes of veg*ns and non-veg*ns?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/677/are-there-any-studies-comparing-genes-of-vegns-and-non-vegns) is pretty clearly asking that. [However, we should probably consider renaming it.](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/108/6) Maybe [scientific-studies](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-studies)?  I like [research](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research), but it can be confused with questions about scientific research in general.

Compare to the single question tagged [science](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science): [How is the presence of consciousness determined in an animal?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/739/how-is-the-presence-of-consciousness-determined-in-an-animal)

This question may receive studies as answers, but possibly not. If an answerer could find a source that's not a study, it would probably work just as well.  Furthermore, this question is asking about the process of science. It's asking how science works as it pertains to veg*nism (<-- possible tag wiki?).

---

So I think we should probably change the two wikis to:

> Use this tag when you are asking for scientific studies as sources for answers to your question. If you are asking about experiments done on animals (an ethical issue for veg*ns), please use the tag [animal-experimentation].

(the first sentence has been modified)

For the belated [research](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research), and rename [research](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) to [scientific-studies](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-studies). (just change the name of the tag, nothing else)

And:

> Use this tag for questions concerning the processes of science as they pertain to veg*nism.

For [science](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science).

Comment: +1 to the distinction which *I think* makes sense. I don't see what's wrong with [research] though, which is more concise and **more likely to occur to the person searching** imho (we could synonymise when people start asking for [scientific-studies])

Comment: @Zanna maybe make it a synonym then? Not sure, but you do have a point.

Comment: I think the tag needs to exist before it can be synonymised (and you know how tags die) so I guess we don't have to pre-emptively synonymise, just write appropriate usage guidance and synonymise when it comes?

Comment: @Zanna I can "merge" tags as a mod, which would rename all + make a synonym. I can do that if/when the time comes.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry as a (scientific) researcher, I have to disagree with this.

**Research is not necessarily scientific**. Many social scientists and humanities researchers will feel excluded by this. Their qualitative and ethical research is clearly also relevant to Veganism.

**Science is not only research**. Science is body of consensus knowledge. Educators, clinicians, and engineers are all experts this knowledge as well as researchers.

I think it is acceptable (in some cases) to ask questions about established scientific knowledge without requiring us to cite widely accepted findings such as Mendel (1865). I don't think we should require tracking down ancient sources or a PhD to discuss science. A wider discourse is what leads to better answers and engagement with the public, not excluding the uneducated from the conversation.

Comment: There's no need to apologise. This is a much clearer take, and now I think what we did with the tags should be reconsidered in light of your good point. I asked this question as I felt that we were giving arbritrary meanings to both science and research... I will review...

Comment: ah I know what my (rather hazy) thinking was! Science is a *subset* of research in the context of this site...